# Flink query submission in Application Mode

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am relatively new to Flink and checking if the following is a good way to submit Flink jobs without sending JARs across. Note: This works locally for me and I am in the process of trying this out on AWS EMR. But want to know if there is anything I am missing here or should be careful about:

In the main method, I set up the necessary data sources and then poll a remote HTTP endpoint for jobs (queries) - something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   //Create env
   //Define sources
   //Define source tables
   Job myJob;
   while ((myJob = getNextJob(..call endpoint..)) != null) {
      //Get the query
      Table resultTable = tableEnv.sqlQuery(myJob.getQuery());
      DataStream<Row> resultStream = tableEnv.toDataStream(resultTable);
      SinkFunction<Row> printSink = new MyHTTPSinkFunction(remoteJobId);
      resultStream.addSink(printSink);
      JobClient jobRef = env.executeAsync(); 
      //Send ack to remote endpoint
   }
}
```

Of course there is additional tracking using listeners and all and edge condition checks (e.g. job failures etc.).

The JAR is put under lib folder of the Flink cluster and then I start it up in Application Mode using [instructions here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/overview/#application-mode).

With this, I am able to submit jobs pretty quickly and get back results with very low latency (currently for batch jobs, but we may use this approach in streaming mode as well). I assume if the JobManager crashes, a backup Job Manager will continue polling and submitting jobs. And with the JobID I can track jobs as well.

Does this appear a reasonable approach? Any feedback will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the application mode currently only supports running a single job in the highly available setup. This is mostly due to the `main()` method being executed in the Dispatcher (part of the JobManager process).

See the https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/overview/#application-mode for more details.

Session cluster is best suited (it's actually an only option right now) for running multiple jobs on a single Flink cluster in highly available setup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One can actually run multiple jobs in Application Mode - the link you posted says this: "Using executeAsync(), which is non-blocking, will lead to the “next” job starting before “this” job finishes." - and I have verified this locally. But your concern on high availability is something that worries me as well. Flink really needs to make job submission easier. The jar way of submitting jobs do not meet our need of transient quick batch queries. So we have been forced to go this route.

Comment: There is also this bit of additional worry from your link: "Additionally, when any of multiple running jobs in Application Mode (submitted for example using executeAsync()) gets cancelled, all jobs will be stopped and the JobManager will shut down". I am thinking of working around this by keeping a second cluster and taking job retries out of Flink to our own. Once Application Mode works better, I hope we can do with just one high availability cluster.

Comment: Session cluster is designed for these kind of use cases. We'll be definitely improving the application mode in the future, but it's not as simple for the multi-job scenario as the main() method might be actually executed multiple times (after failover). The primary goal for the application mode is still with the single streaming job submission.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The part on "but it's not as simple for the multi-job scenario as the main() method might be actually executed multiple times" makes complete sense. While that is not a concern for us for short living batch query jobs, it can definitely be an issue with streaming jobs. I will mark the question as answered. Thanks again!